# Cleaning files with multiple duplicates

Tags: python, database, file

I recently had to copy in emergency my database on my website.

I scraped it using some functions I made in Python using my admin codes.
The database is formated like :

```
Name: 
Phone Number: 
Has played the game:
```

Everything was copied in `.txt` file but sometimes, i find some errors in the file like:

```
Name: Name: Name: Bob
```

How can I clean this mess using shell command or Python but keeping the same order (I want it to still be Name, Phone Number, etc) ?

Comment: Show a larger sample of your txt file.  Is the only problem that sometimes Name: is repeated?  Show each type of anomoly

Comment: The only problem is that sometimes, Name, Phone Number of Has Played the game can be repeated several times in my file on the same line

Comment: Aside from python.what shell are you using linux?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have this in  `db.txt`

```
Phone Number: 
Phone Number: Phone Number: Phone Number: 0118521358 Name: Name: Name: Name: Bob
Has played the game:
Name: Name: Name: Name: Bob
```

You can try a little script like this

```
import re
#create a new file called new_file
new_file=open("new_file",'w')
#open the database file with the discrepancies
file_with_error=open('db.txt','r')
#make a list of all your columns in the db
db_header=['Name:','Phone Number:']
#iterate through each line in your database file and  find matches to replace
for line in file_with_error:
    for col_name in db_header:
        line=re.sub("(%s[ ]*)+" %(col_name,),col_name,line)
    new_file.write(line) #write your new line your file
new_file.close()
exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to run string matching and replacing in your text file fix this. 
You can do this with python or in simply in an editor like notepad++.
search for the expression:

```
Name:.+(Name: (?!Name:).+)
```

and replace it with

```
$1
```

In your text file this expression will find all lines that begin with

```
Name:
```

and replace it with:

```
Name: Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you know how to read the text file line by line in python.  Assuming that you read each line into a string called s

```
>>> s = "Name: Name: Name: Bob"
>>> s2 = "Name: Bob"
>>> 
>>> s_split = s.split(":")
>>> s_split
['Name', ' Name', ' Name', ' Bob']
>>> result = ": ".join(s_split[-2:])
>>> result
' Name:  Bob'
>>> result = ": ".join(s_split[-2:]).strip()
>>> result
'Name:  Bob'
```

the first split will split the string into a list of strings where : is the delimiter.  The join will take the last two strings in the list and join them together with the :.  If the line is normal it works.  It also works for any number of faulty Labels